# Need explanation regarding CSS code

Tags: css

I have the following piece of code in the CSS page of a site

```
left: 0 !important;
```

What does this `!important` mean exactly in this code?

I never seen this anywhere before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS** means that the styles are applied in order as they are read by the browser.

The first style is applied and then the second and so on.

What this means is that if a style appears at the top of a style sheet and then is changed lower down in the document, the second instance of that style will be the one applied, not the first.

For example, in the following style sheet, the paragraph text will be black, even though the first style property applied is red:

```
p { color: #ff0000; }
 p { color: #000000; }
```

The `!important` rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied.

A rule that has the `!important` property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

So if you wanted to make sure that a property always applied, you would add the !important property to the tag.

So, to make the paragraph text always red, in the above example, you would write:

```
p { color: #ff0000 !important; }
 p { color: #000000; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Means, it overwrites all other declarations for the element. More about cascading order here
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order

Answer (score 1):

`!important` is an instruction used in CSS to override other styles that could be further down the cascade or in an inline style attribute on the element.

So for example:

```
.myDiv
{
    color: blue !important;
}


body .myDiv
{
    color: red;
}
```

The color would be blue because it was set to important, even though the other selector is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It means it overwrites any other css left attributes set to the same element or one of the parents

Answer (score 1):

It means, that this statemant override all of the other code.

example:

```
div{
    left: 0px !important;
    } 
div {
    left: 100px;
    }
```

So the div is **0px left**, because of the `!important` it ignore the `left: 100px;`

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> CSS attempts to create a "balance of power" between author and user
>   style sheets. By default, rules in an author's style sheet override
>   those in a user's style sheet. However, for balance, an !important
>   declaration takes precedence over a normal declaration. Both author
>   and user style sheets may contain !important declarations, and user
>   !important rules override author !important rules.